# native_init() Linking Error

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, static-libraries, native

I have used a code from GitHub to make Equaliser for my application but that code gives error here.
Here is a code frm AudioEffect.java .

.................

```
 public class AudioEffect {

          static 
{

System.loadLibrary("audioeffect_jni");

               native_init();
            }
    }
```

.

Already searched on Google but it did not helped

.
I am totally new to this native keyword....so please suggest me how to do it........i am making a music player :).

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

Using NDK use can loadLibrary("audioeffect_jni") read Install NDK and then try this.

https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

The Android NDK is a toolset that lets you implement parts of your app using native-code languages such as C and C++. For certain types of apps, this can help you reuse existing code libraries written in those languages.

Comment: Do i need to download full ndk .or a specific library of it will work ?

Comment: need full ndk and configure, then after it will be work.